# Cancelling call to web-service from application

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a winform app that has two buttons GetData and Close. On GetData I retrieve some data from a web-service whereas Close just closes the dialog. I am calling the web-service on a separate thread. This thread is class instance variable. If getting data from web-service is taking too long and user click on close, I want to cancel that call to web-service and just close the dialog.

What is the best way of cancelling that call to web-service, by just calling abort on thread instance? Any other idea/best practices are welcome too.

Comment: Since the call to webservice is asynchronous, i doubt you could actually cancel it once it's placed.

Comment: OK but if user click on Close button should i simply close the dialog without doing anything or should I abort that thread first?

Comment: I am using something similar on my website where i just close the dialog, but i guess first aborting the thread is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can not cancel it. Once the webservice call is placed then it will get executed even if the calling thread is aborted.

Comment: yeah Dimitri has already mentioned that. Thanks for your response anyways